# Generating PWM from rectified sine wave using 555

Tags: pwm, 555, sine

I want to generate a PWM signal from a rectified sinus wave similar to the image below using [555 timer IC](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/slfs022h/slfs022h.pdf).

[image]

I have designed the circuit below for this.

[image]

I want to get a duty cycle of 80% at the peak of the sine wave, and 0% (5% if not possible) at the zero crossings.

How do I choose R16 and R17 resistor values accordingly? How do I do the calculations?

---

Note: Period of the sinusoidal is 50 Hz. And period of PWM the is

\$ \tau = (R_{11} + 2R_{12}) C_{11} \ln(2) = (101k\Omega) \times (2.2nF) \times \ln(2) = 154 \mu s \implies \text{f} = 6.49 kHz \$ .

Comment: What's the period or frequency of IC11's output? (Save respondents from having to figure that out before working on your actual question.)

Comment: @gwideman I've added it as a note.

Comment: Also, I note that VCC is 15V.

Comment: Why use a 555??

Comment: Mind if I ask: why do you need such a circuit? There must be a better way to do what you are doing.

Comment: Note that with the circuit as drawn, the control voltage to duty cycle mapping will be nonlinear. To linearize it, R15 should be replaced by a current source.

Comment: @VladimirCravero I use 555 for this, because I thought this was the simplest appropriate method. If there is a better way, please name it or give a link.

Comment: @Andyaka When I searched the net for the methods of PWM generation, I saw a lot of such circuits done with 555. So I decided to use 555 for this project. Is there a simpler and better method for this?

Comment: What I was asking is why you need a pwm proportional to this sine wave, anyway there are IC's that do the job, try "voltage controlled pwm generator", one of the first link is this http://www.linear.com/product/LTC6992-1

Comment: @hkBattousai the link provided by Vladimir (above) is what I was contemplating.

Answer (score 1):

The highest voltage into R16 will be at the peak = (20V - 0.6V) = 19.4V

The lowest threshold will be zero. Unfortunately the threshold will be zero the entire time that the sine is < 0.6V.  So there will be a portion of the wave that the PWM output is off, or undefined. To solve that, you might want to add some additional current into R17 (an additional pullup resistor).

But solving with what we have, we want Vthreshmax such that pulse length is ~120us. (80% duty cycle)

Vctl = Vcc * (1- exp(-t/RC) )

Vcc = 15V, t = 120us, R = 10kohm, C = 10nF,

Result: required Vctl = 10.5V

R17/(R16+R17) = 10.5/19.4 = 0.54

R17 = 0.54 R16 + 0.54 R17

0.46 R17 = 0.54 R16

R16 = 0.46/0.54 R17 = 0.85 R17

So, if R17 = 100k, R16 = 85k

Please check the math :-)